# Checking for an enabled outlook account

Tags: c#, outlook

I just started to dabble into using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. I was able to successfully send an email using the bit of code below.

```
public void Send()
{
    try
    {
        Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
        var test = _app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem) _app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mail.To = "testemail@fakeaddress.com";
        mail.Subject = "Test Outlook Subject";
        mail.Body = "Test Outlook Body";
        mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
        ((Outlook.MailItem) mail).Send();
    }
    catch
    {
        Notification.Notice("Error");
    }
}
```

I would like to have a `Validate()` function before the try/catch such that it'll check to see if there's a valid outlook account enabled. May I ask does anyone know how I can check if any outlook accounts are setup?

I tried this

```
public bool validate()
{
    Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
    Outlook.Accounts accounts = _app.Session.Accounts;
    return accounts.Count > 0;
}
```

But accounts.Count returned 1 even after I removed my outlook account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will always be at least one account - the store. Otherwise Outlook won't run. But even if there are mail accounts, how would you know whether they are configured appropriately? Unless you take over the message submission, there is no way for you to know ahead of time.

**UPDATE**: Loop through the `Namespace.Accounts` collection and look for accounts with `Account.AccountType` == olExchange ,olImap,olPop3, olHttp. Keep in mind that OOM only list mail accounts, not store or address book.

If you were using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), you could use `IOlkAccountManager::EnumerateAccounts(CLSID_OlkMail, ...)` (you can play with that interface in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IOlkAccountManager button). If Extended MAPI is not an option, [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am also its author) exposes the [RDOAccounts](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm) object; its  `GetOrder(acMail)` method will return all mail accounts. You'll just need to check if the returned collection has any elements.

Comment: I would just like to know whether there is or there isn't. It's not up to current program to know if it was properly configured or not. That's for the try/catch.

Comment: Your try/catch won't catch any errors - messages submission is asynchronous, you will get an NDR if you are lucky. Also see the updated answer above.